# is there is git function which can be used for restriction in branch name?

Tags: git

I have a requirement to ensure to create git branch must end with:

`[a-z].MAJOR` or `[a-z].MINOR`

How I can achieve it? I have created a unix shell script as a pre-commit setup but it's local. I am not sure how to use it in all the repository. Any help?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
local_branch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"

message="There is something wrong with your branch name. Branch names in this project must adhere to this contract. Your commit will be rejected. You should rename your branch to a valid name and try again."

branch_char=`echo "$local_branch" | awk -F '/' '{print $1}'`

branch_name_MAJOR=`echo "$local_branch" | awk -F '/' '{print $2}'| grep -c ".MAJOR"`

branch_name_MINOR=`echo "$local_branch" | awk -F '/' '{print $2}'| grep -c ".MINOR"`

branch_name_FIX=`echo "$local_branch" | awk -F '/' '{print $2}'| grep -c ".FIX"`

if [[ "$branch_char" == "release" ]]
then
  if [[ $branch_name_MAJOR == 0 ]] && [[ $branch_name_MINOR == 0 ]] && [[ $branch_name_FIX == 0 ]]
  then
    echo $message
    exit 1
  fi
fi
```

Comment: what platform are you using github/gitlab/bitbucket ?

Comment: Port the code to a server side hook like `pre-receive`. Hosting services like Github, Gitlab, and Gerrit have their own equivalent hooks.

Comment: I am using bitbucket.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to install a commit script on all "client" repositories as it would be a huge security issue. It would mean that anyone with access to the repo would be able to run code on all developers' computers.

There are however some tools that facilitate the setup of such hooks like https://pre-commit.com/ if you really want to run them "client-side".

Since you can't force the clients to do it, you will need to enforce it on the server with pre-receive hooks as @ElpieKay is pointing out.